# Is there a difference between an ISR and an interrupt handler?

Tags: c, operating-system, interrupt-handling, isr

I'm studying operating systems and I encountered both the terms ISR and interrupt handler. Are they two words for the same mechanism? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: ISR -> Interrupt service routing. It is same as interrupt handler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference in Interrupt handler and ISR.
[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) says that:

> In computer systems programming, **an interrupt handler, also known as an interrupt service routine or ISR**, is a callback function [...]

Answer (score 6):

ISR is callback for a specific service pertaining to a device/operation/source. There could be multiple ISRs present in a system depending on addresses available in Interrupt Vector table. Where is Interrupt handler is a common routine which is triggered whenever any interrupt comes. Its job is to understand the source of the interrupt and trigger appropriate ISR mapped in Interrupt Vector table.

Answer (score 0):

When interrupt occurs,
interrupt handler performs minimal operations required to respond to the device where as updating the buffer and all other operations are taken care by ISR